# I would like to authenticate users using Radius, but place all successful users in the same home directory with the same shell replacement

Tags: linux, docker, user-profile, pam, radius

I am trying to allow ssh users to be defined in Radius, but share a home directory, shell, etc.  The idea is that all users share the same home directory and default shell (an application).  I would like to avoid creating numerous accounts on the local machine (really a docker container) since their activity is constrained by the application.  I think that I just need to replace the user database information, but I don't understand how to just override that part of the login activity.  Has anyone else done this or should I be solving this a different way?

Comment: It's questionable if this question is not better suited for Server Fault, which I assume. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
because ideally you would provide a minimal code example of what you tried so far.

Comment: In the FreeRadius pam_radius code in file pam_radius_auth.c line 1150 the pam_sm_authenticate function calls pam_get_user(...).  I think this is where the user database comes into play.  (I am new to this code.)  The pam_get_user function is not implemented in the pam_radius code, but it is implemented in the linux_pam code.  In linux_pam  file pam_item.c line 273 the pam_get_user is defined and it returns the user from the pam_handle_t that is passed in *user = pamh->user;

Comment: The pam_ldap module does not have a pam_get_user, but I was expecting it to have one.  So I don't understand how the pieces fit together.  Somehow pam_ldap fills in the pam_handle_t structure, or through some path gets information there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am going to answer my own question.  If you have better information, please contribute.  This question might have been better in ServerFault, but as a programmer I spend more time on StackOverflow so I did not think of that.
The PAM library is useful for single sign-on, but it cannot replace the /etc/passwd file and related files.  PAM and the other assets it brings in supplement the internal Linux info.  So, while you can authenticate with a remote server like Radius, you will still have entries in /etc/passwd.  The control flow is a list of rules in pam.conf and the top-level library works its way down the list letting each module (plug-in) do its work.  Read 'man pam.conf' and 'man pam_mkhomedir' for good information on how this works.
A module implements 6 functions so it is very approachable to add new modules.  See pam_deny.c for the simplest module.
Also, getpwnam is a function you may need in whatever it is you are trying to do.  You can read about that using 'man getpwnam', but you probably already knew that.

Comment: You need  to implement an `NSS` (name service switch) module, in which you can implement how `getpwnam` respond.